# Change image in button of cell Table View Check unheck in Swift also Facing imaged Changed After Scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi I am using Table View and use of button in table View Cell and trying  to change image check Unchecked Button press But facing After Scrolling Change Imaged....
And if i check 1st image then After Few index Image was Automatically selected.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
    let item = categoriesDataCollections[indexPath.row].wishlisted
    cell.heartAction.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.heartAction.addTarget(self, action: #selector(heartWish), for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
        
    if item == "1" {
        cell.heartAction.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-fill-24"), for: .normal)
    } else {
        cell.heartAction.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heartblank24"), for: .normal)
    }
}
    
//MARK:-- Heart Action
    
@objc func heartWish(_ sender:UIButton) {
        
    sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected;
        
    let cell = self.collectionCategoryTable.cellForRow(at: IndexPath(row: urlIndex!, section: 0)) as! CollectionCategoryCell
    let item = categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag].wishlisted
        
    if sender.isSelected {
        cell.heartAction.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-fill-24"), for: .normal)
        let productId = categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag].id
        AddProductWishListApi(AddProduct: productId)
    } else {
        cell.heartAction.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heartblank24"), for: .normal)
        let productID = categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag].id
        RemoveProductWishListApi(RemoveProductList:productID )
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the custom UITableViewCell class where you have the `heartAction` button. I suggest you move most of your logic into that cell, and have a callback which would `AddProductWishListApi` or `RemoveProductWishListApi`.

Comment: The only reason why your changes are not saved and on scrolling they are getting reset is you are just updating in cell not storing changes in UIViewcontroller class.

Comment: thanks..I am getting your points

Answer (score 0):

Your button's selected state is set in your `UITableViewCell` and is being overriden when your tableview recycles the cell. It should be tied to your data source instead.

When you click your button you should update your data source with that value. Something like

```
if sender.isSelected {
    categoriesDataCollections[indexPath.row].wishlisted = true

    cell.heartAction.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-fill-24"), for: .normal)
    let productId = categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag].id
    AddProductWishListApi(AddProduct: productId)
}
```

then you can set it like:

`sender.isSelected = categoriesDataCollections[indexPath.row].wishlisted`

Comment: Thanks... Your Answer also helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to comment, So i'm writing answer here, on tap button are you updating array object wishlist value between 0 or 1?

Because in function "IBAction heartWish" I couldn't find array updating code, As you are not updating Wishlist value because in CellForRow function your image is set on base of this wishlist value "item == "1"

try to update this code in heartWish IBAction function

```
if sender.isSelected {
       
        cell.heartAction.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart-fill-24"), for: .normal)
        let productId = categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag].id
    categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag]. wishlisted = "1"

        AddProductWishListApi(AddProduct: productId)
        
           
       
    }else {
        cell.heartAction.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heartblank24"), for: .normal)
        let productID = categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag].id
        RemoveProductWishListApi(RemoveProductList:productID )
      categoriesDataCollections[sender.tag]. wishlisted = "0"
        

    }
```

Let me know if you need more help

Comment: thanks @Madassir your answer is Helpful for me after Changing let to var in Model But After this Implementation i am facing at first time 3rd,4th,7th,8th,9th index AddProductListapi Failure and second time Selection on check it add product sucessfully. please Help thanks in advance.

Comment: user:6248346 please reply

Comment: addProductListapi failture mean??? can you post picture here?

Comment: addProductListapi failture mean when you tap on button first time api is not called

Comment: Api called but take false response

Comment: can you debug when you tap button what is reason for getting false response?

Comment: ya I debuged my code Solve problem it's Logical error. Thanks....

Comment: Can You Help me Another Problem Like ..... Current time Comprasion with Array of Time ....like [12:00,01:00,02:00,03:00,04:00,05:00,6:00] Actually I am Creating Appointment Page and Use FSCalendar and also Using CollectionView Cell For time Slots ...I want to be set disable Time-Slots If current time pass Array of some time but time slots will work in future Selection Always.....like my current time is 02:00 pm the show 12:00, 01:00 De-Selectable..

Comment: if your problem is solved, please make my answer upvote

Comment: yeah, I can help just compare with current time if time has passed then disable else enable it simple

Comment: ya but I can't implement

Comment: kindly accept and upvote my answer, so it will help others also

Comment: Don't worry it done. and my upvote not showing because I am new Member on stackoverflow So please give my Answer of my Question.